# Ubuntu to windows django project

Tags: django, linux, windows, ubuntu, web

So I have developed several projects in Ubuntu. So I get the projects set up in Windows and run them; they are running properly, but I am facing a problem with the static files, that is, the CSS, showing up when I run the web applications. I have inspected the webapps, and it shows that the CSS and static files are being fetched and served (200 code). So what is the issue, and how can I solve it?

Comment: Please post more detailed description of the issue.

Comment: @PatrykSzczepański, I have django webapplications which I developed in the ubuntu OS, I got issues with ubuntu and so transferred the project folders to windows OS. I set up the projects and got them running in windows. But the issue I am facing is that the static files or styling for some reason is not showing up when I run the application in the browsers. I have tried inspecting the pages and it shows that my static files are being successfully fetched. This is shown by the 200 code. Why could my styling be missing in my webapplications

Comment: Use `DEBUG = True` in `settings.py` and it should work.

Comment: Debug is already set to true